# Watch if variable changed in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I found [meteor variable watcher](https://github.com/gwendall/meteor-templates-watch) and I use it like this:

```
Template.restaurantMap.onCreated(function() {
  this.location = ReactiveVar;

  this.watch("location", function(value){
    console.log('value changed', value);
  });
});
```

It works perfectly. But, is there any Meteor's way to watch ReactiveVar?

I need to watch only one ReactiveVar, not the entire list of attached to Template. And I need to watch it separately from Meteor's template, helpers etc..

I need my own call back in case if variable changed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just use an [autorun](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_autorun), which is a built-in way to create a custom reactive context (function that runs whenever a reactive variable changes). Here's an example:

```
Template.restaurantMap.onCreated(function() {
  this.location = new ReactiveVar;

  var self = this;
  this.autorun(function() {
    return console.log('location changed!', self.location.get());
  })
});
```

Comment: this will not work there will be several ReactiveVar assigned to template. I need to watch only one.

Comment: The `autorun` will only execute again when the reactive variables used within it change. So if only one variable is read, then it seems like it will do what you want. Am I misunderstanding the problem?

Comment: It is exactly what I want. Thank you. Curious how autorun detects that I want to track only this variable and no others that I have defined on the same template. Probably I need to dig more in Meteor's Reactivity.

Answer (score 1):

Any ReactiveVar that is within a reactive computation is automatically watched by meteor. Reactive computations include:

- Template helpers
- Iron router hooks
- Tracker.autorun
- this.autorun

For me, template helpers being reactive is almost always sufficient. When it's not, I use Tracker.autorun or this.autorun (from within the templates onRendered method) instead.

Comment: It is not answer to my question. I asked to watch particular variable independently from Meteor Template, helpers etc..
I need to add my own watcher